# Неправильно выводятся простые числа

Tags: java

Здраствуйте, у меня задание Создать программу, которая находила бы простые числа. Число считается простым, если оно делится только на 1 и на самое себя. Количество найденных простых чисел ограничить числом, введенным с клавиатуры.
Я написал код, вроде все выводится как надо, но при выводе простых чисел у меня сначала выводится непарное число, потом после него парное и только после этого идут только непарные. Не понимаю в чем проблема
Приклепляю код:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Task6 {
        
    public static boolean isPrime(int x) {
        for (int i = 2; i < x; i++) {
            if(x % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите число: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Список простых чисел: ");
    for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
        if(isPrime(x)) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Пример результата
Введите число: 13
Список простых чисел: 1 2 3 5 7 11 13

Comment: Что ещё за парные-непарные числа?

Comment: мне нужно вывести только непарные числа, а почему то одно парное все-таки выводиться

Comment: не понимаю почему

Comment: Что такое парное число???

Comment: типо это 2, 4, 6

Comment: Во-первых, это называется чётное, а не парное. Во-вторых, 2 - простое число. Потому и выводится.

Comment: мне нужно, что б выводились только нечетные числа

Comment: В условии задачи этого нет. Если нужно, то просто не выводи 2 и всё.

Comment: как мне сделать что бы 2 не выводилось? а только нечетные числа

Comment: Любым удобным способом. Можно при выводе проверять на 2, можно проверку на простоту начинать с 3.

Comment: можете подсказать как сделать проверку на 2?

Comment: Вы спрашиваете, как узнать равно ли число 2???

Comment: Страшно встревать в разговор профессионалов. :). А единичку печатать надо? Традиционно она не считается простым числом.

Comment: https://oeis.org/A000040

Comment: Спасибо за статью)

Comment: Теперь все ясно

Comment: Затупил как всегда

Comment: Не обижайтесь. У вас почти правильное решение. Начните цикл с двойки. Больше ничего не надо менять.

Comment: та я уже понял, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сначала проверьте, что все вводимые числа не четные.
2. Затем используйте метод класса BigInteger - isProbablePrime
3. потом используйте Stream,опционально

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите число: ");
    int n = sc.nextInt();
     System.out.print("Список простых чисел: ");
    BigInteger bi ; 
       for(int x = 1; x <= n; x++) {
            if (x % 2 !=0) {
              bi = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    System.out.print(x + "  is Prime := " +bi.isProbablePrime(х) );
        }
      } 
     }
   }
```

Comment: А чтобы не проверять на четность нужно сразу идти по нечетным числам `for(int x = 1; x <= n; x+=2)`. Будет в 2 раза меньше итераций.

Comment: не понял.  мы должны найти  простые  числа  а не нечетные.

Comment: А четное число не может быть простым, потому что делится на 2. У вас в ответе написано - "Сначала проверьте, что все вводимые числа не четные". Так вот чтобы не проверять лишний раз на нечетность, проще сразу исключить четные числа.

Comment: че т о не сообразил  сразу ,  спасибо